# Format a number with leading sign

Tags: java, formatting, numbers, currency

How do I format in Java a number with its leading sign?

Negative numbers are correctly displayed with leading `-`, but obviously positive numbers are not displayed with `+`.

How to do that in Java? My current currency format string is `\#\#\#,\#\#\#,\#\#\#,\#\#\#,\#\#0.00` (yes, I need to format positive/negative currency values)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use a negative subpattern, as described in the [javadoc for DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("+#,##0.00;-#");
System.out.println(fmt.format(98787654.897));
System.out.println(fmt.format(-98787654.897));
```

produces (in my French locale where space is the grouping separator and the comma is the decimal separator) :

```
+98 787 654,90
-98 787 654,90
```

Comment: Additionally for Kotlin users  we can do something like this
`val pattern ="%+.2f"; val num =1.232432432f ; println(pattern.format(a));`
outputs `+1.23`

Answer (score 20):

API for [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) provides an example:

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
System.out.println(formatter.format(Locale.FRANCE, "e = %+10.4f", Math.E));
//e =    +2,7183
```

Answer (score 9):

I did:

```
private NumberFormat plusMinusNF = new DecimalFormat("+#;-#");

Integer newBalance = (Integer) binds.get("newBalance");
bindsForUpdate.put("plusMinus", plusMinusNF.format(newBalance));
```

which formatted positive integers, e.g. 5 to "+5" and negative integers, e.g -7 to "-7" (as expected)

Answer (score 1):

> It requires a little tweaking of the
>   DecimalFormat returned by
>   NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() to
>   do it in a locale-independent manner.
>   Here's what I did (tested on Android):
>
> ```
> DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
> String symbol = formatter.getCurrency().getSymbol();
> formatter.setNegativePrefix(symbol+"-");
> // or "-"+symbol if that's what you need
> formatter.setNegativeSuffix("");
> ```
>
> IIRC, Currency.getSymbol() may not
>   return a value for all locales for all
>   systems, but it should work for the
>   major ones (and I think it has a
>   reasonable fallback on its own, so you
>   shouldn't have to do anything)

[ageektrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631/ageektrapped)

Source: [Format negative amount of USD with a minus sign, not brackets (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056400/format-negative-amount-of-usd-with-a-minus-sign-not-brackets-java)