# format double-type numbers with or without leading sign (+/-)

Tags: java, numbers, double

To output an equation, I need to format the leading sign of my numbers. If the number is positive and at the front of the equation, I should omit the "+" sign but keep the "-" sign if it's a negative number. The numbers are from user input, and by default, a user would not type "+" for a positive number.

in Java, how do you format numbers if you want to have a leading "+" sign ? thanks

Comment: You want leading `+` sign or omit it? You are saying both the things.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Format a number with leading sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243316/format-a-number-with-leading-sign)

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the equation can be printed separately.
for example

```
 public class Equation
 {
      public int real;
      public int imagi;

     public void print()
     {

         System.out.print(real);
           if(img > 0)
           {
               System.out.print("+");
               System.out.print(img);
          }
         else
          {
               System.out.print(img);
          }

      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) says

> DecimalFormat patterns have the following syntax:
>
> ```
> Pattern:
>     PositivePattern
>     PositivePattern ; NegativePattern
> ```

so `new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0###;-#,##0.0##")` should prefix with a sign only in the negative case.