# Java printing symbol for positive number

Tags: java

I have a Java program that does a bunch of calculations from some user inputs and at the end it has to print the equation of the plane. Format of the equation of the plane is 6x-2y+3z-4=0.

To get the values 6, -2, 3, & -4 is from a bunch of calculations. So i was thinking to print out the equation is to

```
System.out.println("Equation is: " + aa + "x" + bb +
"y" + cc + "z" + gg + "=0");
```

Where aa, bb, cc , gg corresponds to the 4 integers above. But the output is

```
Equation is: 6x-2y3z-4=0
```

It seems to print the minus signs in there for the negative numbers but how can i have it print out a plus sign if the number is positive? Like in between -2y3z should be 6x-2y+3z-4=0

Comment: well you need to add `+` manually

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243316/format-a-number-with-leading-sign

Comment: well what if it wasn't the z variable that was positive but instead it was the y variable? or what if it was all variables plus the constant that were positive? h

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `System.format()`:

```
System.out.format("Equation is: %dx %+dy %+dz %+d = 0\n", aa, bb, cc, gg);
                                     ^    ^    ^
```

Specifying the `+` flag would include the sign whether positive or negative.

You can find more information about formatting numeric output [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`printf()` to display a formatted output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html):

```
int aa = 6;
int bb = -2;
int cc = 3;
int gg = -4;

System.out.printf("Equation is: %dx%+dy%+dz%+d=0", aa, bb, cc, gg);
```

Here you are ussing the format modifier `%+d`, to specify that the **sign must be displayed**, even if the number is positive.

**Output:**

```
Equation is: 6x-2y+3z-4=0
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add + in your string for positive numbers. you can do something like following. So better take a string and add your variables there. While adding consider following three things

1. if the variable is 0 dont add that part at all.
2. if the variable is positive add a '+' then the variable
3. if the variable is negative just add the variable