# Java negative bigdecimal value with braces

Tags: java

I have a string that I'm trying to parse into a BigDecimal. I'm using the following regex to strip all non currency symbols with the exception of -,.()$. Once it has been stripped, I'm then trying to create a BigDecimal with the remaining value. The problem begins when a negative value comes across in brackets. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to repair this instance?

```
(1000.00) fails
```

I'm assuming I must somehow convert the brackets to a negative sign.

code sample.

```
public BigDecimal parseClient(Field field, String clientValue, String message) throws ValidationException {
    if (clientValue == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        clientValue = clientValue.replaceAll( "[^\\d\\-\\.\\(\\)]", "" );
        return new BigDecimal(clientValue.toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        throw new ValidationException(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't describe the format of your input string. Is it really so strange, that you cannot use a DecimalFormat instance to parse the string? If not, why are you trying to reinvent the wheel by manipulating the string yourself?

Comment: Does this help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056400/format-negative-amount-of-usd-with-a-minus-sign-not-brackets-java

Comment: The values are entered in by a user. Those values very as such, $5,000.00, 5,000.00, 5000.00, 5000, -5000.00, (5000.00), ($5000.00), (-5000.00), ($-5000.00). In the end they need to either be 5000.00, (-5000.00), -5000.00 so that they can be passed into a bigdecimal.

Comment: @GJ13, I've seen that post, but I don't understand how the format will strip the unwanted characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to detect the `(` and `)` characters yourself, then strip them out, create a BigDecimal from the rest of the string, and negate it.

```
if (clientValue.startsWith('(') && clientValue.endsWith(')'))
{
   return new BigDecimal(clientValue.substring(1, clientValue.length() - 1)).negate();
}
else
{
   return new BigDecimal(clientValue);
}
```

Comment: This would almost work, however when you have (-1000.00) which is a valid value negates to positive 1000.00

Comment: Then you'll need to detect a possible '-' character at the start of the substring, and if it's there, don't negate, so that your result stays negative.

Comment: That's what I did although mathematically wouldn't that be a negative number?

Comment: There's 2 ways of indicating a negative number: The normal mathematics minus sign, e.g -1000.00, and the accounting way, e.g. (1000.00).  Your first comment indicates that if BOTH are given, e.g. (-1000.00), that the number should be remain negative.  That's what drove my first comment above.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think parentheses are correctly interpreted by `BigDecimal`? `(1000.00)` is incorrect input [according to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29). You must use `-` symbol (`-1000.00`). Supported format is strictly defined in JavaDoc. In general it's optional symbol (`+` or `-`) followed by digits, dot (`.`) and exponent.

For example this is valid input: `-1.1e-10`.

Comment: So your suggesting appending the negative sign after the first brace?

Comment: Okay, I must of simply overlooked this since the CurrencyFormatter was sending the values to the frontend without the minus sign causing it to fail when being submitted to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

[DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is a more appropriate tool for the job:

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)");
myFormatter.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal) myFormatter.parse("(1000.00)");
System.out.println(result); // -1000.00 for Locale.US
System.out.println(myFormatter.parse("($123,456,789.12)")); // -123456789.12
```

As you can see, not only will it deal with negative patterns, but also with currency signs, decimal and grouping separators, localization issues, etc.

Take a look at [The Java Tutorials: Customizing Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) for further info.