# How to customize number format in freemarker?

Tags: java, html, freemarker, number-formatting

I am using freemarker and trying to display numbers in this format: `$3,343,434.00` for example. This was easily taken care of by using `${total?string.currency}` (assuming "total" is some number).

However, when I have negative numbers, it's showing them like this: `($343.34)` instead of this: `-$343.34`. I need the negative sign instead of the parenthesis. Is there a way I could customize the formatting so it does everything that the `string.currency` did but replace the negative value behavior? I am relatively new to freemarker, so detailed responses are appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also try `?string(",##0.00")`. However in this case you need to explicitly add `$` and `-` sign would be after `$` in case of negative numbers.

```
<#local total = 3343434/>
$ ${total?string(",##0.00")}  //$ 3,343,434.00

<#local total = -3343434/>
$ ${total?string(",##0.00")}  //$ -3,343,434.00
```

OR in case if you want what was expected you can replace the strings.

```
<#local total = -3343434/>
<#local total = "$ " + total?string(",##0.00")/>

${total?replace('$ -','- $')}   //- $3,343,434.00
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: Since FreeMarker 2.3.24 you can define named custom number formats, which can be an alias to a number format pattern (or even a formatter implemented in Java, but that level of flexibility isn't needed in this case). So add a custom number format called "money" as an alias to `"¤,##0.00"` to the FreeMarker configuration, and then you can write something like `${total?string.@money}`. See: http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html

Currently FreeMarker just uses the formatting facility of the Java platform, so it's only as configurable as that (assuming you want to use `?string` and `?string.somethingPredefiendHere`). Which is not much... but, in general, the formatting categories provided by the Java platform is not fine-gradient enough anyway, I mean, you don't have application-domain categories like, price-of-product, a salary, a price on the stock, etc. (This demand is more frequent with non-currency numbers though.) So I think, generally, you want to make a formatter function, that you can use like `${salary(someNumber)}`, `${price(someNumber)}`, etc. Those functions can be implemented in a commonly `#included`/`#imported` template like a `#function` or in Java by using `#assign salary = 'com.example.SalarayMethod'?new()` in place of `#function`, where `com.example.SalarayMethod` is a `TemplateMethodModelEx`.

Answer (score 1):

How about taking a mod of your number, convert it to the required string format and finally add a '-' prefix to the final string. You can retain the default format in just two steps.

Answer (score 1):

```
${amount?string("$,##0.00")}
```

Result: -$100.00 or $100.00 regarding the sign.

Answer (score 0):

Freemarker uses the currency formatting provided by the Java platform.

It requires a little tweaking of the DecimalFormat returned by NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() (which is what is called when you call .currency). You can see [examples of it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056400/format-negative-amount-of-usd-with-a-minus-sign-not-brackets-java).

However, that said it will likely be more effective for you to create a macro in freemarker to call which will handle your specific formatting.

Sorry for not having an example of what that macro would look like, but it's a good starter into macros in freemarker since you are just learning.

You might investigate if you can supply a custom format using the exposed configuration for [number formats](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html) that will meet your needs.

Comment: Date and number formatting is better done in `#function`-s then in `#macro`-s, unless you formatting is HTML markup (colors and such).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the default currency formatting (in case you need to use a locale other than '$'), you can just replace the parentheses like so:

```
${transaction.amount?string.currency?replace("(","-")?replace(")","")}
```

This will work without error regardless of if a number is negative or positive.

**TIP: Make sure the number is actually a number with the `?number` directive before converting to a currency format**