# How do we change the default currency on freemarker if we have the desired currencycode in string?

Tags: java, freemarker

How do I change the default currency in the currency format of a number in freemarker? I only have the three digit currency code in string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps don't use the ?string.currency -format at all and do the formatting yourself?

For example...

```
${user.locale.currencySign} ${price.forLocale(user.locale)}
```

..

Answer (score 1):

You could use string formatter options to change the currency symbol like this:

```
${value?string["¤ ,00;; currencyCode=${currencyCode}"]}
```

if you have the ISO 4217 code for the currency, or

```
${value?string["¤ ,00;; currencySymbol=${currencySymbol}"]}
```

if you have the currency symbol.

Some examples (for value 1234.56):

| Parameters | Result |
| --- | --- |
| CurrencyCode: EUR | **€ 1234.56** |
| CurrencyCode: BRL | **R$ 1234.56** |
| CurrencySymbol My$ | **My$ 1234.56** |

More details in https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

The Freemarker `currency` format is defined by the `Locale`. You can change the locale in your Freemarker settings.

You can also manually override the `.locale` variable in your template using the `setting` directive.

```
<#setting locale="en_US">
```

Documentation:

- [Freemarker: Built-ins for numbers](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_string_for_number)
- [Freemarker: Settings](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_settings.html)
- [Freemarker: setting directive](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html#ref.directive.setting)

Comment: Correct, FreeMarker just provides what the Java platform does. Which is often found to be not enough... see my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20965738/606679

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is : For example on en_US I have to write $ 1,230.12 , I can use the default locale. However I just need to replace the currency symbol to € but keep the number format same. If I change the locale to something like fr_FR, it will become 1 230,12 €. But I need € 1,230.12