# Replace the minus sign on a number and replace/enclose the negative number in a parentheses

Tags: freemarker

Freemarker Code:

${customrecord_line.amount?string("(,##0.00)")}

Actual result = -1234.56

Expected result = (1234.56)

Note: customrecord_line.amount represents the amount

Comment: Someone had else wanted the opposite result : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960069/how-to-customize-number-format-in-freemarker

Comment: yep. read that earlier but hoping to find another answer as I'm not familiar with Java. I'm using a cloud application and on that application I'm creating a pdf template using freemarker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `;` to separate the pattern of the non-negative and negative numbers. If you omitting the `-` from the dedicated negative pattern then it won't be automatically added to the output. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html.

Example:

```
<#setting number_format="##0.00;(##0.00)">
${1.5}
${-1.5}
```

Output:

```
1.50
(1.50)
```

Of course, the `"##0.00;(##0.00)"` pattern can be used with `?string(...)` as well. It was just more convenient to specify it only once. (Also, if you can adjust the FreeMarker configuration settings, you can define a custom number format alias, which makes this even more manageable. See http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html).