# Java Currency Formatter adding parenthesis to the negative values

Tags: java, formatting, number-formatting

I am trying to use Number Formatter and while formatting the negetive value , it appends () around it.

here is the code

```
double amount =-200.0;
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");      
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(amount));
```

when I look at the formatter , It has negative prefix as "($". which does the damage. I am using java.text.NumberFormat for the number formatter.

Is there any other formatter that can be used that does not add "()" to my negative value. ?

Comment: Here is more about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056400/format-negative-amount-of-usd-with-a-minus-sign-not-brackets-java

Answer (score 1):

add this two line with your curreny formatter

```
currencyFormatter.setNegativePrefix("-")
currencyFormatter.setNegativeSuffix("")
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much. Second line did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better to avoid currency formatter in this case? You can try universal decimal formatter instead:

```
double amount = -200.0;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00;$-#,##0.00");
String result = formatter.format(amount);
System.out.println(result);
```

Pattern which is passed into the constructor prevents from using brackets for negatives (and of course you can change it in any way you like).

Comment: It helps if you can explain your answer, rather than just dumping some code.