Display negative currency with parentheses using NumberFormat
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
Number value = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse("-1234.876");
String output = numberFormat.format(value);

I have the code above. The output is -$1,234.88. I want the output to be ($1,234.88). Is there a way to do this using NumberFormat, getCurrencyInstance, and Locale? (I only need this to work for USD in the US.)
I see that a Currency Format style of "account" should give me parentheses, but I'm not clear on whether I can use that with Locale. If I can, I don't understand how. I did try adding Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US","account"); before the other code.
I know I can use manipulate the String to get what I want, but I am hoping that there are Java methods to do it for me.
Note that this question is the opposite of the one at Java Currency Formatter adding parenthesis to the negative values. In Java 8, the parentheses were the default, and that user was asking how to get rid of the parenthesis and use the minus sign.

I believe this is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59577441/4722577

This question is similar to: Java Currency Formatter adding parenthesis to the negative values. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

alternative: new DecimalFormat("¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US)) ( you can avoid the need for the symbols by using  $ instead of ¤ ) -- (( or, to use the "account" style: new Locale.Builder().setLocale(Locale.US).setExtension('u', "cf-account").build()  ))

You can do:
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US-u-cf-account"));

https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1yzp
The string argument passed to Locale.forLanguageTag is a IETF BCP 47 language tag. Returns a Locale object, which in turn we pass in a call to NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance.

Some explanation would enhance this Answer.

I added a bit of prose with links. But an explanation of the language tag would be a big help.

Wow. I never would have never figured that out, even with that Wiki link. It sure seems that more documentation is needed somewhere!

Well, it looks like the Java 23 docs have information about this https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/23/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html. That never came up in my many searches. In fact when I search for "Java 17", the Java 8 docs still come up earlier in my hits.

Something like this:
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

// Cast to DecimalFormat to customize the negative pattern
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
decimalFormat.setNegativePrefix("($");
decimalFormat.setNegativeSuffix(")");

Number value = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse("-1234.876");
String output = decimalFormat.format(value);

System.out.println(output);

